# Aspell with CKEditor

Tags: ckeditor, aspell

When i use 'spellchecker.pl' as the server script for spell check with Aspell in CKEditor, the source code is displayed in the Spell Check Dialog Box instead of the text with mispelled words.

Can someone help please?

Answer (score 2):

I use aspell with ckEditor 3x, and here's how I got mine going.

Assuming you are in a linux/PHP environement and already have aspell installed and functioning on your server, the next thing to get is the aspell plugin:  http://cksource.com/forums/download/file.php?id=512

Copy the extracted aspell folder to your ckeditor/plugins folder so that you end up with ../ckeditor/plugins/aspell/

Next, configure the toolbar by editing your ckeditor/ckeditor.js file.  Mine has all the whitespace removed, so I used alt-F to look for toolbar_Basic and added ,'SpellCheck' to the end of the list, similar to what I use here:

```
i.toolbar_Basic=[['Bold','Italic','Underline','-','NumberedList','BulletedList','-','SpellCheck','Source']];
```

You can also add SpellCheck to the toolbar_Full array in the same way.

*Don't forget to remove the OEM "SpellChecker" toolbar option if it is in your default toolbar.  Note difference in aspell's toolbar name "SpellCheck" and the default ad-supported name "SpellChecker".*

Finally, you'll need to tell ckEditor to use the new aspell plugin.   I use the PHP API for ckEditor, so I handle it like so:

```
$CKEditor->config['extraPlugins'] = 'aspell';
```

If you use Javascript, you can add it with this:

```
config.extraPlugins = 'aspell';
```

Save all files, make sure you've uploaded everything to the server in the correct folders, and test the editor.